# Set-builder Notation for Sets of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, multisets

I have two questions about the set-builder notation for sets of sets. Technically, I believe they are multisets as multiple instances of the same element are allowed.

Let $A_i$ be a set of integers and let $\{A_i\}$ be the set of all sets $A_i$. Suppose set $A_i$ is given by $A_i = \{a | M_{ai} > 0\}$, where $M$ is a matrix. In other words, set $A_i$ contains the row indices $a$ of all elements in column $i$ of matrix $M$ which are greater than 0.

1. How does one define the "inverse" case, i.e. $\{I_a\}$, from $\{A_i\}$ in set-builder notation?

Example:

Suppose

$$
M = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

then

$A_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$,
$A_2 = \{\}$,
$A_3 = \{1, 3\}$

and

$I_1 = \{1, 3\}$,
$I_2 = \{1\}$,
$I_3 = \{1, 3\}$.

My idea would be: $I_a = \{i | \exists A_i \in \{A_i\} : a \in A_i\}$. Suppose $a = 1$ then $I_1 = \{i | \exists A_i \in \{A_i\} : 1 \in A_i\}$.

2. What is the total number of elements in all sets in a set $\{A_i\}$ called (in this case 5) and is there a notation convention similar to the cardinality of a set? The cardinality of $\{A_i\}$ would be 3 but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not sure to understand... But assuming usual matrix notation $(a_{ij})$, we have that $I_i= \{ j \mid a_{ij} > 0 \}$

Comment: And the "cardinality" will be the usual sum of the elements of the three sets and not the number of elements of their union.

Comment: Yes, except $J_i = \{j | a_{ij} > 0\}$ maybe the notation I used is a little confusing. The question is how does one define $I_j$ from $J_i$, or from $\{J_i\}$.

Comment: Clear, thanks... Maybe we have discovered why a $3 \times 3$ matrix is a matrix and not a set of $9$ numbers...

Comment: Transpose * is the normal term for what you did .

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.